# No visualisation of ComboBox items with MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox

I am working with MVVM and I can´t see my list in my View. I want to initialize the list in my MV and to bind the DataContext my View.XAML. Nevertheless I cannot make the values to appear on my ComboBox.

**View.XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NewLUT_ViewModel x:Key="NewLUT_ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="Grid" DataContext="{StaticResource NewLUT_ViewModel}">
    <ComboBox x:Name="lutBox" ItemsSource="{Binding AllLUTLibraries}">

    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**View.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    protected NewLUT_ViewModel New_VM
    {
        get { return (NewLUT_ViewModel)Resources["NewLUT_ViewModel"]; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class NewLUT_ViewModel
{
    List<ILUTLibrary> AllLUTLibraries { get; set; }

    public NewLUT_ViewModel()
    {
        //TODO: Initial parameters
        AllLUTLibraries = Objects.LUTLibraries.Instance.AllLUTLibraries; 
    }
}
```

Comment: list needs to be a public property of the ViewModel, not a field.

Comment: @Peregrine thank you very much, you are totally right!

Comment: @Peregrine and what if I had an already populated List? I have updated my code, but I can not see any of my items in the List

Comment: `public List<ILUTLibrary> AllLUTLibraries { get; set; }`